# SDK2: Cant get UserStories when querying Portfolio Items

Tags: rally

Is this a bug?  When I query for portfolio items, and in the store I fetch:

```
fetch: ['UserStories', 'HierarchicalRequirement']
```

I don't see any children of the PI in the data returned.  I checked with the manual API for that same OID and confirmed it does have children.

If I do a query with HierarchicalRequirements instead of PortfolioItems, and fetch the 'Children' field, I can see the entire Hierarchy.

What gives with PI's?  Is the query broken for children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying against the generic PortfolioItem endpoint will return you PIs from all levels of the hierarchy- most will have a Children collection of PIs.  Only the bottom level PI will have a UserStories collection.

Assume you have a PI hierarchy like so:

Top
Middle
Bottom

To get Top items you'd query the PortfolioItem/Top type and fetch Children to include the Middle items.

To get Bottom items you'd query the PortfolioItem/Bottom type and fetch UserStories to include its children.

**Edit:** I'm able to get user stories back using this code in both 2.0p3 and 2.0p4:

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
    model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
    context: this.getContext().getDataContext(),
    fetch: ['UserStories', 'Name', 'FormattedID'],
    autoLoad: true,
    listeners: {
        load: function(store, records) {
            Ext.each(records, function(record) {
                var stories = record.get('UserStories');
                Ext.each(stories, function(story) {
                    console.log(story.FormattedID + ' - ' + story.Name);
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, but that's the thing-- I'm querying feature level portfolio items that I know have sub stories, but they are not returned in the query though they should be based on the fetch array I am using.  I am able to see the progeny if I query by HierarchicalRequirement (and I understand that's via a different property "Children") but no luck with PI's.  I'm using 2.0p3.

Comment: Does your code look similar to the above?  If you run that snippet do you get results back?

Comment: Ok, that's the deal.  I was using model: 'PortfolioItem', not 'PortfolioItem/Feature'.  The stories were not there for just 'PortfolioItem'.  Thanks!

Comment: I can get the stories based on a specific Feature. But how does it look if you have a specific Initiative, that has Children Features? I would think that you loop through the Features to collect the respective Stories. But the Initiative object just has a single Children reference. How do you create the data store based on a single Children ref?

Comment: Checkout this guide on fetching collections: http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/guide/collections_in_v2-section-collection-fetching